# How do i access a file inside the angular 10

Tags: file-upload, angular10

My folder structure of Angular 10 project is given below

> -Backend 
> -e2e
> -node_modules
> -src

I want to access backend/uploads/profilepic.jpg in the angular's index.html page. Simply, i just want to load an image file in the front end which is uploaded in the backend folders.

Answer (score 0):

A static resource, like an image, is either bundled inside the angular webapp, by adding it to the assets folder (e.g. 'src\assets\images') and have that folder referenced inside angular.json:

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
],
```

Or, make the backend serve that image and simply access it from the frontend like this:

```
<img alt="xyz" src="https://yourdomain/img_test.png">
```

If both the backend and frontend are hosted on the same domain, you can use relative path for the URL, i.e `https://yourdomain` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. In order to access the files of the 'uploads' folder which is located in the backend folder. I have to make that folder static. for that in my server.js file, I have added below code

```
app.use('*/uploads',express.static('uploads'));
```

after that, I could load my image file from that uploads folder by calling
http://localhost:8090/uploads/image.jpg